# Rotate Object from Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to rotate a polygon made in XAML with C# code, however I'm stuck on the Propertypath. Does someone know what I should use instead?

This is the C# code I have right now:

```
public void Rotate()
{
    Storyboard rotate = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    myDoubleAnimation.From = 0;
    myDoubleAnimation.To = 360;
    myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Polygon.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, Arrowhead.Name);
    rotate.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
    rotate.Begin(Arrowhead);
}
```

And here is the polygon(triangle) I want to rotate in XAML:

```
                <Polygon Fill="#41b1ff"
                 Stroke="Gray"
                 StrokeThickness="2"
                 Points="80,60,100,40,100,40,120,60" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Grid.RowSpan="3"
                 Name="Arrowhead"
                     />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. You need to add the transform you're trying to modify though:

```
<Polygon
        Fill="#41b1ff"
        Stroke="Gray"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Points="80,60,100,40,100,40,120,60"
        Name="Arrowhead">
    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
</Polygon>
```